# Weight painting seems to be ignored on my rig

Tags: animation, weight-painting, rigify

I'm trying to animate my character model using Rigify, but moving one foot will always bring the other foot with it.  I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1FBVsbJHMs).

My Blender project file can be found [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/31193).  As you can see in the project, the feet are weight painted, and I set the FK/IK to 1.0, as shown in the video.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found 2 issues here :

- First, you forgot to **apply the mirror** modifier.
- Second, you can see that it is not the "foot" weight that influences the other side, but the "toe" weight (and this is a side-effect of the mirror modifier I guess) :

[image]

So make sure to **apply the mirror modifier** before parenting the armature, then try again. You'll be able to tweak the weight painting more efficiently.

And a side note, you'd better to pull up the Armature modifier before the Subsurf modifier (you'll get better performance while moving the rig, so the animation will be less painful;)

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by parenting the armature?  I'm still very much a Blender noob.  Does it have something to do with the way the skeleton is built?  I just used the default one provided by Rigify.

Comment: It's when you select the armature and the character mesh, then type Ctrl+P and select "with automatic weight". (on the tutorial you linked in your question, it's @ 3:25)